# Debug level messages in logcat with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat, android-debug

Just moved to Android Studio from eclipse, and my logcat DEBUG messages have stopped showing.

I have seen some solutions that use adb setprop, but is there a way to set VERBOSE level to all tags and all applications?

This seems like a basic thing when running apps in debug from within Android Studio...

Comment: Are you seeing other messages? What device are you using? I've had a lot of trouble on certain machines (older Macbook Pros, specifically) with certain devices (Galaxy S3) getting _any_ logcat messages to show, unless I'm directly debugging the app (Debug window rather than the Android window).

Comment: I am seeing INFO and above and using a Windows 8.1 machine with a Nexus 4 device.